# Set SSL connection for CachingConnectionFactory

Tags: spring, spring-amqp

I want to set SSL connection factory for CachingConnectionFactory. I tried this:

```
com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
cf.setHost(HOST);
cf.setPort(PORT);
cf.setUsername(USERNAME);
cf.setPassword(PASSWD);
cf.setVirtualHost(VIRTUAL_HOST);
cf.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false);
cf.setConnectionTimeout(10000);
if (useSSL) {
    try {
        cf.useSslProtocol(sslContextConfiguration());
        System.out.println("Configuring SSL context...");
        } catch (IOException | TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(cf);
connectionFactory.setAddresses(ADDRESSES);
connectionFactory.setChannelCacheSize(25);
admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
```

So far the only solution that I found is to set `useSslProtocol` for `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory` and set it to `CachingConnectionFactory(cf)`.

Is there some better way?

Comment: I am unlikely to spend much more time answering your questions until you start taking advice.

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced use Annotations for configurations.

Comment: See the edit to my answer - Spring Boot auto configuration can set SSL for you.

Answer (score 3):

CachingConnectionFactory is now capable of auto-setting SSL by using URI instead of hostname:

```
connectionFactory.setUri("amqps://xxx");
```

enables SSL in the background

Comment: this doesn't support multiple addresess

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct; the framework does [provide a factory bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#_rabbitconnectionfactorybean_and_configuring_ssl) for the rabbit factory, but that's really to make is easier to configure when using spring XML configuration.

> Is there some better way?

So, there is no "better way" to turn on SSL, except, as I've now said to you several times over the last couple of weeks...

```
connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(cf);
admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
```

...you really should let Spring manage these objects for you instead of using `new...`.

**EDIT**

Also see the [spring boot property in the appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-rabbitmq)

`spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=false` # Whether to enable SSL support.

and boot will auto-configure SSL for you.

Comment: Hi Gary, I tried the above solution but I received java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error when trying to write to rabbitMq! any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you are connecting to the non-ssl port? In any case, you can debug SSL with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html Also look at the rabbitmq server log; if you still can't figure it out, ask a new question with much more information, config, etc.

Comment: Hi @Gary, please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74852612/caused-by-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-socket-write-erro