# Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm trying to connect to rabbitMQ over SSL using Spring Boot 2.7.4 and java 11.0.14 I was following this example [here](https://github.com/Nepitwin/RabbitSSL):

I have added the following configurations:

properties file:

```
# RabbitMQ Server configuration file.
rabbit.username=admin
rabbit.password=admin
rabbit.host=localhost
rabbit.port=5671
rabbit.ssl=TLSv1.2
rabbit.keystore.name=client_key.p12
rabbit.keystore.password=rabbitstore
rabbit.truststore=server_store.jks
rabbit.truststore.password=rabbitstore
```

client_key.p12 and server_store.jks are in my classpath.

Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:rabbit.properties")
public class RabbitConfiguration {

    /**
     * Default sample channel name to respond for requests from clients.
     */
    public static final String DEFAULT_QUEUE = "sample_queue";

    /**
     * Environment properties file from rabbitmq configuration.
     */
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    /**
     * Establish a connection to a rabbit mq server.
     * @return Rabbit connection factory for rabbitmq access.
     * @throws IOException If wrong parameters are used for connection.
     */
    @Bean
    public RabbitConnectionFactoryBean connectionFactoryBean() throws IOException {
        RabbitConnectionFactoryBean connectionFactoryBean = new RabbitConnectionFactoryBean();
        connectionFactoryBean.setHost(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("rabbit.host")));
        connectionFactoryBean.setPort(Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("rabbit.port"))));
        connectionFactoryBean.setUsername(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("rabbit.username")));
        connectionFactoryBean.setPassword(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("rabbit.password")));

        // SSL-Configuration if set
        if(env.getProperty("rabbit.ssl") != null) {
            connectionFactoryBean.setUseSSL(true);
            connectionFactoryBean.setSslAlgorithm(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("rabbit.ssl")));

            // This information should be stored safely !!!
            connectionFactoryBean.setKeyStore(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("rabbit.keystore.name")));
            connectionFactoryBean.setKeyStorePassphrase(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("rabbit.keystore.password")));
            connectionFactoryBean.setTrustStore(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("rabbit.truststore")));
            connectionFactoryBean.setTrustStorePassphrase(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("rabbit.truststore.password")));
        }

        return connectionFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * Connection factory which established a rabbitmq connection used from a connection factory
     * @param connectionFactoryBean Connection factory bean to create connection.
     * @return A connection factory to create connections.
     * @throws Exception If wrong parameters are used for connection.
     */
    @Bean(name = "GEO_RABBIT_CONNECTION")
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(RabbitConnectionFactoryBean connectionFactoryBean) throws Exception {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory(Objects.requireNonNull(connectionFactoryBean.getObject()));
    }

    /**
     * Queue initialization from rabbitmq to listen a queue.
     * @return An queue to listen for listen receiver.
     */
    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        // Create an new queue to handle incoming responds
        return new Queue(DEFAULT_QUEUE, false, false, false, null);
    }

    /**
     * Generates a simple message listener container.
     * @param connectionFactory Established connection to rabbitmq server.
     * @param listenerAdapter   Listener event adapter to listen for messages.
     * @return A simple message container for listening for requests.
     */
    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {

        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(DEFAULT_QUEUE);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        return container;

    }

    /**
     * Message listener adapter to generate a message listener.
     * @param deviceMonitoringReceiver Device receive to for listening.
     * @return A message listener adapter to receive messages.
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(DeviceMonitoringReceiver deviceMonitoringReceiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(deviceMonitoringReceiver, "receiveMessage");
    }
}
```

Also I have updated rabbitMQ configurations:

```
[
  {rabbit, [
     {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
     {ssl_options, [{cacertfile, "D:\\tls-gen\\basic\\result\\ca_certificate.pem"},
                    {certfile,   "D:\\tls-gen\\basic\\result\\server_seliiwvdec53152_certificate.pem"},
                    {keyfile,    "D:\\tls-gen\basic\\result\\server_seliiwvdec53152_key.pem"},
                    {verify,     verify_peer},
                    {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true}]}

   ]}
].
```

But the application is not starting and throwing

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

Comment: As I suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099354/set-ssl-connection-for-cachingconnectionfactory/51101527#comment132032516_51101527 use `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to debug SSL problems, and look at the server log.

Comment: There is no errors in the server logs! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding this to the configurations:

```
ssl_options.password = xxx
```

It's mentioned in the official documentation it's optional I don't know why. But whatever the issue is now resolved.